# More elegant way of finding generating function coefficient

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am looking to find the number of ways to pay a £50 bill in £1 and £2 coins. The generating function for this is $g(x)=(1+x+...)(1+x^2+...)$, which after a few lines of algebra becomes

$g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1+i)x^i\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^jx^j$.

The following is the only formula I can think of for finding the coefficient $\alpha$ of $x^{50}$ in $g(x)$

$\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^{50}(-1)^k(51-k) = 26$,

but this feels quite tedious. My first question is whether or not this answer is correct. The second is whether there is another, more elegant way to find this coefficient $\alpha$.

Comment: Try to write the g.f. as $A/(1-x)+B/(1-x)^2+C/(1+x)$ for some constants $A,B,C$. Then, expand each of these three terms in a series.

Answer (score 3):

The number of ways to pay for a £50 bill is equivalent to the number of £2 coins that can be used to make an amount less than or equal to 50 as the rest of the bill can be paid with £1 coins. This leaves 26 options for the number of £2 coins: 0, 1, ... 25.

Answer (score 2):

We need to find the number of ways to obtain $n$ from summing $1$ and $2$ (assuming order is unimportant, i.e. the $1$s are indistinguishable, as with the $2$s).

Note that the number of $2$s we can choose is anywhere from $0$ to $\lfloor {\frac{n}{2}} \rfloor$, and the number of $1$s is uniquely defined from the number of $2$s we choose. So the number of ways is $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1$, and this is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the generating function. So in the case of $n=50$, the coefficient is simply $26$.

Answer (score 2):

We  use  the  *coefficient of* operator  $[x^n]$  to denote the  coefficient of $x^n$  of  a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{50}]g(x)}&=[x^{50}]\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)\\
> &=[x^{50}]\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{50}]\frac{1+x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}\\
> &=\left([x^{50}]+[x^{49}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{j}(-x^2)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^{50}]+[x^{49}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)x^{2j}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=26}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* expansion twice.
- In (2) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ and use the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion.
- In (3) we apply the rule $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^{50}$ noting that the coefficient of $x^{49}$ does not contribute.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using generating series, as started in the OP, may go along the following lines:

We work in the power series ring $\Bbb Q[[x]]$, then the expression $E$ we want to expand around zero is
$$
\begin{aligned}
E
&=(1+x+x^2+\dots)(1+x^2+x^4+\dots)
\\
&=\frac 1{1-x}\cdot\frac 1{1-x^2}
\\
&=\frac {1+x}{(1-x^2)^2}
\\
&=(1+x)\left(1+2x^2+3x^4+4x^6+\dots+(k+1)x^{2k}+\dots\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The coefficient of $x^{50}=x^{2\cdot 25}$ in the last factor is the only one contributing to the product, this is $(25+1)$.

---

Computer check:

```
sage: R.<x> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ)
sage: 1/(1-x)/(1-x^2)
1 + x + 2*x^2 + 2*x^3 + 3*x^4 + 3*x^5 + 4*x^6 + 4*x^7 
  + 5*x^8 + 5*x^9 + 6*x^10 + 6*x^11 + 7*x^12 + 7*x^13 
  + 8*x^14 + 8*x^15 + 9*x^16 + 9*x^17 + 10*x^18 + 10*x^19 
  + O(x^20)
```

(Output was manually broken to fit in page.)

---

Note that in general, one has to use partial fraction decompositions (over $\Bbb C$) and for the pieces use as here the binomial coefficients from $(1+h)^{-N}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{-N}kh^k$ for $h$ being a (complex) constant times a power of $x$. See also the comment of **Gerry Myerson**.